# How can use filter and contains with multi-ArrayList in Kotlin so I only have elements which match the condition?

Tags: kotlin, filter

I have a class called Person

```
data class Person(
    val id: Int,
    val name: String
)

data class IDs(
    val id : Int,
    val active : Boolean )
```

and an array list that has numbers of ids and another list of Persons

```
val myStu = listOf<Person>(Person(1, "Name_1"), Person(2, "Name_2"), Person(3, "Name_3"))
var ids = listOf<IDs>(IDs(1,false),IDs(2,true),IDs(3,true))
var newIds = listOf<Int>(2,3,4,6)
```

First I want to apply two actions to the myStu, **first** is to have a list that include all the items from myStu that his id matches the id in the IDS and only if the active is true

myStu or the new list will have the values

```
Person(2, "Name_2"), Person(3, "Name_3"))
```

Then do **action two** , I need to add a new item to the new list that their id does not exist in the newIds , in another word we will add a new person Person(4,"None") and (6,"None) , 4 and 6 values come from newIds list

the final output will be :

```
   id= 2 name = "Name_2", id= 3 name = "Name_3", id= 4 name = "None" , id =6 name="None"
```

I want to write the code with filter , I failed with first step because I don't know how to use contains() with the list inside the filter

```
val newArr = myStu.filter {
    ids.contains(it.id)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "easiest" way of doing that would be to use `filter` directly, there's no need for `contains`. If we were to use contains, then we would need to also search for which element contained the id, in order to get the status. We can just do a [.any()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/any.html) to do both at the same time.

V1

```
val activeStu = myStu.filter { person -> ids.any { it.id == person.id && it.active } }

val result = newIds.map { newId ->
    activeStu.find { it.id == newId } ?: Person(id = newId, name = "None")
}
```

Another method, that might work a bit better if we have big lists, would be to first transform the `IDs` list into a map. That way the second part of our code is a bit more efficient, since there is no search involved.

V2

```
val idsMap = ids.associate { it.id to it.active }
val activeStu = myStu.filter { idsMap[it.id] ?: false }

//the creation of the result list is the same
```

---

Version without creating 2 new lists. This works, but it might be quite ineficient processing wise, and also harder to understand what is going on IMO.

V3

```
val result = newIds.map { newId ->
    //try to find an IDs with the current newId and status as true
    when (ids.find { it.id == newId }?.active) {
        //if found, then find the corresponding Person  
        true -> myStu.find { it.id == newId } ?: Person(newId, "None") // if this happens, it means that an IDs with status true existed and no Person had that id. Not sure what you want in this scenario, this version creates one of the "none" persons.
        //if not found, then create a new one
        else -> Person(newId, "None")
    }
}
```

Note: depending on what version of kotlin you have, you might have to change the when statement to this:

```
when (ids.find { it.id == newId }?.active == true)
```

Since I think I remember that `null` didn't used to be treated as `false` in old versions (I've run this with version 1.4.20).

Btw, you can also use this version with the `idsMap` from V2, just replace the `when(...)` with `when(idsMap[newId]` or `when(idsMap[newId] == true)` depending on the kotlin version.

Comment: Thank you so much Alex , is it possible to do the work without creating two lists (activeStu and result), what I mean is to have one list and do these steps

Comment: I've added that, although I'm not sure that is better than the others.